# Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel

i am showing data from database to show.blade.php but this problem is showing
following is the code:
**BlockController**

```
public function show(Blog $id)
    {
        //
        $blogs = Blog::findOrfail($id);
        return view('blog.show', compact('blogs'));
    }
```

**show.blade.php**

```
@section('content')
    
        <h3>{{ $blogs->title }}</h3>
        
@endsection
```

output of dd($blogs):
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnIFH.png)
i tried all the options that i get but still not working..

Comment: whats the output of `dd($blogs);` ???

Comment: because your blog does't have `title` parameter, try to dd your blog `dd($blogs)` and see what parameter that blog send.

Comment: show you Blog schema.. or blogs table.

Comment: As STA said, debug it in the controller. If that works, then `dd($blogs->title)`

Comment: i add dd($bogs); image above please have a look

Comment: Check your route, I think you are not  using `BlockController@show` in your route

Comment: @STA, i check dd($blogs); in show.blade.php it is not showing any parameters what i need to do now ??      "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1213 ▼
  #items: []
}"

Comment: what is `$id` supposed to be, do you have a route parameter for this route definition?

Comment: change `public function show(Blog $id)` to `public function show($id)`

Comment: when i remove blog from, public function show(Blog $id)  it works thank you (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that method signature `$id` is a Model instance. Eloquent Models implement `Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable`. If you pass something that is `Arrayable` or is an array to `find`, which `findOrFail` is calling, it will treat this like you are looking for multiple records and will return a Collection.

You have a Collection and not a Model instance.

If your method signature didn't type hint the Model it would make more sense as you would have the 'id'. If you are type hinting Models for those methods usually you would be using Route Model Binding.

Route Model Binding:

```
public function show(Blog $blog)
{
    // $blog is the matching record
}
```

Without Model Binding and just getting the parameter:

```
public function show($blog)
{
    // $blog is just the 'id' or what ever you decided to pass in the URL
}
```

Your routes have a parameter named `blog` because your resource is named 'blog'. For Implicit Route Model Binding to be in place you have to match the parameter name to the parameter name in the signature.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `show(Blog $id)`, $id is of instance Blog::class

What you need to do next `$blogs = Blog::findOrfail($id->id);`